# Android BufferedReader and DataInputStream byte availability

Tags: android, bufferedreader, datainputstream

I'm having trouble using Buffered Reader.  If I use the readline() and just wait until it goes null, it works perfectly in letting me know I've read all that needs to be read, the problem is that readline strips off newline chars (\n and \r) which create other problems in my post-parsing.

I tried moving to just using a read of maxbuf size, and using reader.ready() to tell if there's something to be read, but I can't differentiate between it underfilling the buffer (because it couldn't release that much at the moment) and underfilling the buffer because it's out of data.  Ready() just says a read operation won't be blocked, it doesn't seem to differentiate between being out of data and just not being ready.  Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Best yet, does anyone know if it's possible to use readline and not strip off the newline chars?  I can't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by scrapping the ready() call; the -1 seems to be a safer check.  Found some online statements that ready() was worse than useless, and I think I agree.  So, now if I get a -1, I consider myself done, and if I get a 0 I just assume it wasn't ready; anything else is a success, and I continue until I hit a -1.

Answer (score -1):

```
String line = in.readline();
line += '\n'; // or "\r\n" if you like
```

Comment: can't do that, because I don't know what they would have added.

Comment: What does it matter if it was \n or \r\n ?